# Right way to get references to an object in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I want to find all the objects referencing my object.

I came up with this query, **Is this the best way to get all references to an object?** (I know this doesn't include constraints, I handle that separately)

**Direct References to Object**

```
SELECT object_id, owner, object_name, object_type
       FROM sys.DBA_OBJECTS  
       WHERE object_id IN (select object_id
                           from public_dependency
                           where REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID = :id_object)
       ORDER BY object_name
```

Also, on the internet, I have come across queries like the following.

**Direct and Indirect References to Object**

```
SELECT object_id, owner, object_name, object_type
       FROM sys.DBA_OBJECTS  
       WHERE object_id IN (SELECT object_id
                           FROM public_dependency 
                           CONNECT BY PRIOR object_id = referenced_object_id
                           START WITH referenced_object_id = :objectId)
```

However, if my understanding is correct, this query doesn't return direct references only, but also indirect dependencies.

For example if I want the references for object_A. If object_B references it, and object_C referenced object_B. This query would return object_B and object_C as references to object_A. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with some people with more Experience in Oracle than me, they told me I was right in my understanding.

This query returns the references to an object (except the constraints)

```
SELECT object_id, owner, object_name, object_type
       FROM sys.DBA_OBJECTS  
       WHERE object_id IN (select object_id
                           from public_dependency
                           where REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID = :id_object)
       ORDER BY object_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select referenced_owner || '.' || referenced_name as table_name,
       referenced_type as type,
       owner || '.' || name as referencing_object,
       type as referencing_type
from sys.all_dependencies
where referenced_type in('TABLE', 'VIEW')
      and referenced_name = '[TABLE_NAME]' -- put your table/view name here
      and referenced_owner = '[OWNER]'
order by referencing_object;
```

Comment: please add always some text and explain what you are trying to achieve